# Change tooltip content by Tippy js v6

Tags: javascript, tooltip, tippyjs

I'm using clipboard js to copy-paste content and there is a tooltip attached to the button by Tippy js.

But how do I change the tooltip content and make it appear for two seconds as long as the clipboard success event is fired? I cannot think of a way to change the content because I'm not using the prop but the attribute method.

Possible related doc:

https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/constructor/

https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/tippy-instance/

https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/methods/

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');

tippy('.btn', {
    placement: 'bottom',
    theme: 'clean'
});

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    //Change the tooltip content and show for two seconds
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Testing...123" data-tippy-content="Tooltip">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get instance of your tippy object and call some methods on it in your event listener.

```
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');

const btnTippy = tippy('.btn', {
    placement: 'bottom',
    theme: 'clean',
})[0]; // 0-index used because tippy will return array of buttons here. You can use `querySelector` that will return only one instance if don't need array.

const copiedTippy = tippy('.btn', {
    placement: 'bottom',
    theme: 'clean',
    trigger: '',
})[0];

copiedTippy.setContent('Just copied')

clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
    copiedTippy.show()
    setTimeout(copiedTippy.hide, 2000) // to hide tip after 2 seconds
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but the tooltip disappears as soon as the mouse leaves the button...The expecting result should be showing the tooltip for two seconds even if the mouse leaves the button. The content should update back to the original one after 2 seconds...Any idea how to do this please

Comment: I think that you asked not the right question. As I understood you want to show another tooltip after user clicks the button. If so you need two separate tooltips for that purpose. One — for showing Tooltip and another one — for showing Message after click.

Comment: I updated the answer according to my last considerations